# How to fix Relative imports python problem

Tags: python, file, import

i want to import file that is in parent folder and i dont want to do this with ***sys***

my files:

```
import/
   sub_folder/
       x.py
   a.py
```

file a.py:

```
def spam():
    print "gg"
```

file x.py:

```
from .. import a

def main():
    a.spam()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

***this is the error-*** Attempted relative import in non-package

I tryed all and nothing works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with \_\_init\_\_.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports don't work on files that get executed as the main file.

Relative imports depend on the `__name__` attribute - which is set to `__main__` if you're executing that file directly.

You need to execute that file **as a package**

```
python -m import.sub_folder.x
```

And you need to put some `__init__.py` files in the folders to make python recognize them as packages